# Flash - load Flash on page

Tags: flash

I have a flash , when i scroll page to flash's position , flash will be loaded.

It look likes load images when we scroll some where , images will be showed in there.

But i don't like this in flash , i want flash always ready when flash even not include on screen that we are seeing

How to disable this feature ?

Answer (score 1):

2 months and no answers. Maybe this has something to do with the clarity of your question. I am, for one, not sure exactly what you're asking.

**I wonder if you are talking about a flash swf in a web page?** - and you only have the flash/swf content loading when you scroll page (down?) and reach the position of the swf?

If this is the case it seems pretty uncommon, to me anyway. Usually all items on a web page loads (in the order they are written into html) from the browser starts building the page to the last item is done. I think you need to describe your problem more clearly - if you still have it, that is.